# How to write php code inside the article in Joomla?

Tags: php, articles, administrator, editing

I have a Joomla article and I need to implement "@include ...." in the article source code, so it loads a PHP page from external link, but only this article should display the PHP page.

I searched in Admin panel, navigated to that article, but the editor says that the article source code is empty.

Any solutions ?

thanks

Comment: So you're loading via an iframe? Ajax? The notion of editing "source code" runs counter to the whole point of a CMS.

Answer (score 2):

You can not include PHP code in articles. But there are extensions that will help you to achieve it, for example [Sorcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer).

Once installed, you can add your PHP code into your article like so:

```
{source}
  <?php
      include PATH_TO_FILE.php
  ?>
{/source}
```

Comment: great , Dmitry , I am wondering if I can avoid that and route the article body to a PHP page , because the external PHP page is going to be the entire article

Comment: I am not sure that this is possible. May be create a menu link to the external PHP script (link). Not clear what exactly you want to achieve? May be it you can update your question or ask a new one?